Iphone broken image carousel (working on desktop/android)
I have a working infinite image carousel on desktop/android but on Iphone the images disappear and reappear randomly during the animation (or so I think).
The gallery is from Elementor and the animation is CSS with translateX. Any ideas?
Link: https://test.mydemoapp.gr/
Screen recording from Iphone: https://test.mydemoapp.gr/iphone-capture.mp4
